# PHP - Encrypt / Decrypt functions

Tags: php

I'm using the next function I found on the net for encrypt and decrypt a string.

The code working great and I'm pleased with this mechanism. Only problem I  found is that if you run the encrypt function with same value multiple times you getting different hash result.

I would love to get your help understand why the its changing all the time and fix this issue so it will always return same hash for same value:

```
public function encrypt($string)
    {
        
        $i = $string;
        $keychars = 'AISXD5H2FIWB81KE76JY93V4ORLAMT0QDUNG';
        
        $divider = 19;
        
        $biasDivider = 14;
        
        $noise = 53;
        
        if ($i < 0) {
            throw new Exception('Expected positive integer');
        }
        
        $i = $i + $noise; // add noise to a number
        $bias = $i % $biasDivider;

        $res = '';

        while ($i > 0) {
            $div = $i % $divider;
            $i = intdiv($i, $divider);
            $res .= $keychars[$div + $bias];
        }

        // Current version of an algorithm is one of these chars (if in the future you will need to identify a version)
        // Remember this chars on migrating to a new algorithm/parameters
        $res .= str_shuffle('LPTKEZG')[0];
        $res .= $keychars[$bias]; // Encoded bias

        return $res;
        
    }
    

public function decrypt($code)
    {
        
        $keychars = 'AISXD5H2FIWB81KE76JY93V4ORLAMT0QDUNG';
        
        $divider = 19;
        
        $biasDivider = 14;
        
        $noise = 53;
        
        $keychars = $keychars;
        $biasC = substr($code, -1);
        $bias = strpos($keychars, $biasC);
        $code = substr($code, 0, -2);
        $code = str_split(strrev($code));

        $val = 0;

        foreach ($code as $c) {
            $val *= $divider;
            $val += strpos($keychars, $c) - $bias;
        }

        return $val - $noise;
        
    }
```

Comment: Probably due to this part: `$res .= str_shuffle('LPTKEZG')[0];` - that shuffles this string, so that the characters will be in a random order afterwards, and then picks the first one of those.

Comment: You right I removed that line and now its returning the same hash value. but now the decrypt function not working well. What I have to do modify in the decrypt function?

Comment: I have not checked the algorithm in detail, but it extracts parts of the encrypted value via their position there when it decodes. The easiest thing to do would probably be to not _remove_ that line, but pick one of the characters out of that list yourself, and then simply add that one every time. (What that possibly does for the "stability" of the algorithm, if it could make attacking/cracking the whole thing a bit easier, I couldn't tell you. But as you were using code you did not understand to begin with, that probably doesn't make too much of a difference any more at this point either.)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using the openssl encrypt and decrypt for PHP. Here is an example on how you can do so

```
function encrypt($string, $key)
{
    $iv = random_bytes(16); // Generate a random initialization vector

    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($string, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

    $result = base64_encode($iv . $encrypted); // Combine IV and encrypted data

    return $result;
}

function decrypt($encryptedString, $key)
{
    $data = base64_decode($encryptedString);

    $iv = substr($data, 0, 16); // Extract IV from the encrypted data
    $encrypted = substr($data, 16); // Extract encrypted data from the string

    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

    return $decrypted;
}
```